# GTalk and phone with wrong time

Tags: google-talk, clock

I have a phone where I like to have the time a few minutes forward the right time. Now, when I chat with people through Google Talk, I got all message mixed up because the received messages arrive with the sender time. If the answer is faster than my forwarded minutes, it appears before my message.

Example:

```
Phone 1 time        Phone 2 time       Sender       Message time        Message
08:01               08:18              Phone 1      08:01               I'm fine
08:00               08:17              Phone 2      08:17               How are you?
```

Is there anything I can set up (beside the right phone time) to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, except perhaps a different chat application that can interface with Google Talk. Talk uses the timestamp of the sender to order the messages, using the assumption that cellphones on a cell network will have a consistently accurate clock. It is likely that a different chat application (such as [IMO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imo.android.imoim) or [Trillian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ceruleanstudios.trillian.android)) which interfaces with Google Chat will display these messages differently; I do not use multi-protocol chat applications, or change my clock, so I cannot confirm that this will solve your problem; I remain rather confident it will however.

Answer (score 1):

Check the time zone you have set under *Settings -> Date and time* and make sure that it's correct. I had the same problem on my Samsung phone and this solution fixed it.

Comment: He deliberately choose a different time so while this would fix the problem, it was noted in the question that he doesn't want to do this.